# Error in If Statement- Need Assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Working on a document that should be color coded when out of tolerance. When less than 1% go green, when more than 1% go red. What is the problem?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @fixer1234 what would the equation be when the percentage is either negative or positive?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Do you mean you are concerned only with the magnitude, not the direction?  If so, you could test ABS(G7)<.01

Comment: @fixer1234 when the percentage is negative and over 1% it's GOOD, but when the percentage is positive and over 1% it is bad. The formula needs to work whether it's -.01 or +.01 but not over.

Comment: Doesn't Ben Sampica's answer do that?  Anything less than +1% will evaluate as good, including all negative numbers.

Comment: @fixer1234 it does not, see here (the 4 should be negative). http://i.imgur.com/GS7kDWK.png

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for -1 < x < 1? If so add in a conditional like If c.Value < 1 And c.Value > -1 Then

Comment: @BenSampica current statement is =IF(G7<0.01,"GOOD","BAD"), what would your statement be?

Comment: Edited answer to reflect your new information.

Comment: @BenSampica perfect, you are the best! Thank you again fixer1234.

Comment: Please accept as the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're getting a lot of green. Shouldn't it be:

```
IF(G7 < .01,"GOOD","BAD")
```

EDIT: From new information
Sounds like you're looking for -1 < x < 1? If so add in a conditional like:

```
=IF(AND(G7>-.01, G7<.01), "GOOD", "BAD")
```

Comment: To explain it a little bit:  .01 = 1%, 1 = 100%